# Retrofit2 asynchronous callback isn't called

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have this very straightforward piece of code using the library `retrofit-2.1.0`

```
public class UserManager {
    private static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MY_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    private static final UserService service = retrofit.create(UserService.class);

    public static User getUserById(Integer userId) {
        Call<User> call = service.getUser(userId);
        final User[] user = new User[1];
        final boolean[] isCalled = {false};

        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                System.err.println("CALLED");
                user[0] = response.body();
                isCalled[0] = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                isCalled[0] = true;
            }
        });
        return user[0];
    }

    interface UserService {
        @GET("users/{user_id}")
        Call<User> getUser(@Path("user_id") Integer userId);
    }
}
```

I'm calling it from JUnit4 test.

```
public class UserManagerTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetBattleById() throws Exception {
        User user = UserManager.getUserById(1);
    }
}
```

My `User` class is fine and GSON is able to serialize `JSON` into it. URL is also fine.

The problem is neither `onResponse`, nor `onFailure` is actually called. `isCalled[0]` remains `false`, `user[0]` remains `null` and I don't see anything in stderr.

I've googled this issue and found some very similar cases but unfortunately no real solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [It is called](http://ideone.com/PPHi95) but not then where you thinking...

Comment: You cannot return the user right after the call... It will always return null because the request is async and you are using it in a synchronous way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return the result in the method like that. You'll need to wait for any of the two callbacks and then have an interface to send the result to the Calling method. **That's is because the `enqueue` method is asynchronous, you can't get the result directly after calling the method**.

Something like

```
public interface OnGetUserCallback {
    void onGetUser(User user);

    void onError(Throwable t);
}

public static void getUserById(Integer userId, OnGetUserCallback onGetUserCallback) {
    Call<User> call = service.getUser(userId);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            onGetUserCallback.onGetUser(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            onGetUserCallback.onError(t);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you really need your own interface? Use the provided `Callback<User>` as the parameter

Comment: You don't have to, but I won't pass the Callback object itself like that. Interfaces makes things more clear when having callbacks like this. As we can suppress the whole implementation of the UserManager, but the interface will be the same. Like changing the network lib for instance or changing the data source itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are using enqueue in a **Synchronous** way, which will always return you **null** because the request haven't completed yet when you return... Try this way just to see if thats works:

```
User user = call.execute();
```

If you want to use the **Async** feature, you would need some sort of [BroadcastReceiver](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) to fire when the request is done to inform the view that the data is now retrieved. You can also use an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for that purpose.

Also you are trying to assign a `User` to a `Battle` Object...

Comment: Which would obviously cause NetworkOnMainThreadException ... **edit:** there is no need for using BroadcastReceiver nor EventBus ... what is enough: is to move the code into onResponse ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Assignment `User` to `Battle` is just a typo. I tried using synchronous calls but I've got this exception and decided to try using `retrofit` in asynchronous was because I don't want to bother with threads.

Comment: It's actually less complicated related to thread if you use synchronous call...Can you post here the exception you got?

Comment: @Selvin he can't just move the return in the onResponse, it won't work since the method won't wait to get there to return...

Comment: It was a shorthand from: move all code that depends on result into onResponse

Comment: @Selvin Dude... have you heard about the callback hell... You'll just end up with a big pizza slice using this kind of coding. What if he needs another call inside and another one...etc

Comment: Yes, I heard ... I heard also about EvenBus's hell and BroadcastReceiver's hell, too ...

Comment: You just need to learn how to use them ;) Good coding is never easy

Comment: Good coding follow KISS principle ... you just need to learn it ;) ... BroadcastReceiver is just the callback (especially when you are using LocalBroadcastManager) ... and the same story with EvenBus (you also need to implement it's callback) ...

Comment: Oh I guess nested async call follows KISS principe that's right... *i'm done here*